# Roaming profiles and Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a working roaming profile on Windows Server 2008 R2. Now I would like to open Outlook 2007 and find my *.pst data whatever machine I login to.

What is the best/most correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft ***strongly*** recommends against actively accessing a .pst file via a network share. You can read [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/01/21/network-stored-pst-files-don-t-do-it.aspx) for some insight as to why, or just search Google for 'pst network share' for additional info.

If your .PST is of any decent size, you will also be generating a significant amount of network traffic on login/logout as the profile is synced from and to the server as Dave M points out.

Comment: Interesting, then how can I do this? We are a small company of 5 clients...

Comment: Probably not the answer your looking for, but the 'MS' way would be to use Exchange server. With a small organization of 5 users, something like Windows Small Business Server 2011 would probably be a better fit, as it provides a single unified license for Windows Server and Exchange.